# Testing sidekiq worker and retryset Rails minitest

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

I have a sidekiq middlware which catch custom exception

```
require 'celluloid'
require 'sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs'

module Sidekiq
  class RetryMiddleware < Sidekiq::Middleware::Server::RetryJobs

    def call(worker, msg, queue)
      yield
    rescue Sidekiq::Shutdown
      # ignore, will be pushed back onto queue during hard_shutdown
      raise
    rescue Sidekiq::Retries::Retry => e
      # force a retry (for workers that have retries disabled)
      msg['retry'] = e.max_retries
      attempt_retry(worker, msg, queue, e.cause)
      raise e.cause
    rescue Sidekiq::Retries::Fail => e
      # seriously, don't retry this
      raise e.cause
    rescue Exception => e
      # ignore, will be pushed back onto queue during hard_shutdown
      raise Sidekiq::Shutdown if exception_caused_by_shutdown?(e)
      raise e unless msg['retry']
      attempt_retry(worker, msg, queue, e)
      raise e
    end

  end
end
```

and my worker looks like below

```
class SomeWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options retry: false

  def perform(input_data)
    begin
     logic to insert data into db
    rescue Ione::Io::ConnectionClosedError => e
     raise Sidekiq::Retries::Retry
    end
  end

end
```

When i was trying to test the SomeWorker peform method is adding the job to retry.
In Testing I am not seeing the middleware is getting called

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You're making this way too hard on yourself, just call the methods.

```
RetryMiddleware.new.call(MyWorker.new, { ... }, 'default') do
  MyWorker.new.perform(...)
end
```